# Selenium WebDriver Error: No Such Frame Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run this: https://github.com/jmopr/job-hunter

I executed it via the command: `rails server`. collected a few job postings to apply to, then when i clicked on "Apply to jobs" a window popped up but none of the information that was to be submitted to indeed.com got pasted in the forms. The window then closed and it went on to the next job profile. It doesn't seem like it is able to select the proper frame, and i'm not sure exactly what causes this.

main error:

```
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170831-19043-haskqi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10840:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame': Unable to locate frame: 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchFrameError)
```

Since i suspect the main culprit here are compatibility issues, here are a list of software and specific gems that may be out of date or updated in a way that makes it incompatible:

> Firefox: 45. Ubuntu 16.04. Geckodriver  1.18.0(irrelevant???)
>   Selenium: 0.2.11. Selenium webdriver: 2.53.0.

I tried playing around with different versions of firefox, the webdriver to see if i had any compatibility issues, no success. Here is the rest of the error:

```
Started GET "/users/apply" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-31 14:08:21 -0700
Processing by JobsController#apply as HTML
User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Job Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE (score > 40)
Running via Spring preloader in process 19571
applier.rb:121: warning: key "How did you hear about this job?" is duplicated and overwritten on line 127
^C[2017-08-31 14:08:31] INFO  going to shutdown ...
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/childprocess-0.5.9/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:148:in `sleep': Interrupt
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/childprocess-0.5.9/lib/childprocess/abstract_process.rb:148:in `poll_for_exit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/binary.rb:59:in `quit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/launcher.rb:62:in `quit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb:77:in `quit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:175:in `quit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:248:in `quit'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:20:in `block in browser'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `fork'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:161:in `serve'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
[remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170831-19571-ugrrq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10840:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.switchToFrame': Unable to locate frame: 1 (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchFrameError)
from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170831-19571-ugrrq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170831-19571-ugrrq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
from [remote server] file:///tmp/webdriver-profile20170831-19571-ugrrq/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:70:in `assert_ok'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:78:in `create_response'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:90:in `request'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `call'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:649:in `raw_execute'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:627:in `execute'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:206:in `switchToFrame'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/target_locator.rb:37:in `frame'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:151:in `within_frame'
from applier.rb:29:in `scrape'
from applier.rb:169:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:60:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:123:in `require_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `runner'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/mo/Desktop/job-hunter-master/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

The sad part is that I had this work before. It drives me crazy not to be able to replicate it. Could missing packages be causing this? Do we need to install the jar files (but i'm not using windows!!) as prompted when you first install the selenium gems?

Code (applier.rb):

```
def scrape
unless @job.applied
  visit @job.url
  unless page.has_css?('p.expired')
    page.find('a.indeed-apply-button', match: :first).click

    page.driver.within_frame(1) do
      page.driver.within_frame(0) do
        complete_step_one
        complete_additional_steps
      end
    end
  end
  Job.delete(@job.id)
  page.close
end
```

Comment: can you show the line of code causing the error? Keep in mind that if you are writing an automated browser to interact with a third party site, all bets are off - they can change the html structure at any point.

Comment: It seems you are trying to switch to Frame 1. Try switching to Frame 0 or show us your code.

Comment: @Kapil Uploaded the code. Sorry for not including it earlier.

Comment: @maxpleaner Yes that is a useful reminder. Meanwhile i've uploaded the code, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @AlannaMueller - Did clicking on apply button is successful through automation?

Comment: @Kapil yes, but complete_step_one doesn't work because it can't find the proper frame.

Comment: @AlannaMueller - I checked on Indeed.com and there was no frame. Try after commenting both frame line code.

Comment: @Kapil Sorry i haven't got the chance to respond in a while. I've commented both frames in the code. Nothing pops up at all this time, at least with the code we commented, we do get a popup. I believe we have the right frames, but something else must be wrong.